# JQuery Validate Image Upload File Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, upload

I have a JQuery script that validates the upload of avatar images but I need it to prevent the upload of anything **other than PNG, JPG & GIF** images.  Any way of implementing this into the code I have? Here is the code:

```
$('#addButton').click(function () {
    var avatar = $("#avatarupload").val();
    if(avatar.length < 1) {
        avatarok = 0;
    }
    //ELSE IF FILE TYPE
    else {
        avatarok = 1;
    }
    if(avatarok == 1) {
        $('.formValidation').addClass("sending");
        $("#form").submit();
    }
    else {
        $('.formValidation').addClass("validationError");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Isn't there a way of checking the file name for the extension? Like, `if(avatar.name includes jpg){}` sort of thing?

Comment: stuff like this can be easily manipulated and create lot of unsolved edge case if done using makeshift methods like the one I see below - do it cleanly on the server end or use proper HTML5 if you are focussing on reliability.

Comment: Of course you can validate on client side without File API, Check my answer.

Comment: I plan on checking it server side too but I just wanted to try to prevent the upload script being executed if possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should check the file extension

```
var extension = avatar.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
if (extension!="PNG" && extension!="JPG" && extension!="GIF" && extension!="JPEG"){
    avatarok = 0;
}
```

So the full code should looks like

```
$('#addButton').click(function () {
    var avatar = $("#avatarupload").val();
    var extension = avatar.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
    if(avatar.length < 1) {
        avatarok = 0;
    }
    else if (extension!="PNG" && extension!="JPG" && extension!="GIF" && extension!="JPEG"){
        avatarok = 0;
        alert("invalid extension "+extension);
    }
    else {
        avatarok = 1;
    }
    if(avatarok == 1) {
        $('.formValidation').addClass("sending");
        $("#form").submit();
    }
    else {
        $('.formValidation').addClass("validationError");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution if the OP is prepared to assume that users will always save their files with extensions...

Comment: Yeah, you'd still need to check the mime type and data server side

Comment: Thanks @Original10 - This will work to display an error but it shows an error for valid files too - Any ideas why?

Comment: Just updated the answer with where the code should fit within your existing code

Comment: @Original10 - Yes that's exactly what I have but it runs the error even if I'm adding a JPEG

Comment: It says Invalid Extension JPG

Comment: Ah yes, of course - Those have caught me out on several occasions - Working fine now - Huge help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try for jquery validate for validation which is having accept :

```
vCategoryImage:{
   accept: "image/*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement the purpose is upload avatar ,so you can check with drop zone open source file upload extension [Drop Zone](https://www.dropzonejs.com).

Or else you can check with the various plugins available from Jquery.

For Example plugin please check the below links

- Lite Uploader - File type and size validation and more functionality. [Lite Uploader](https://github.com/burt202/lite-uploader)
- Resumable JS - [Resumable JS](http://www.resumablejs.com/)

Hope this will be helpful.