# allow click in a button if image is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a form to upload image.

I want to disable this button and enable it only when user selected some file. Any ideas how can I make it work?

```
<form action="/upload.php" id="upload" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="file_input">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload_btnb" disabled>
</form>
```

how to enable button when user select a file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Validate Image Upload File Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950373/jquery-validate-image-upload-file-type)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I don't want to validate image, just to enable button when an image is selected!

Comment: That means you need to check if the added file is an image, right?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan no, user can add an exe if he wants... after that I want to enable the button... PHP will solve the exe problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following.

```
$('#photo').change(function(){
   $('#upload_btnb').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:
HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:file').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val()) {
           $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
           // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
           // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`